# Why does IEnumerable<T> derive from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

#### Duplicate:

> [Why IEnumerable<T> inherits from IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221691/why-ienumerablet-inherits-from-ienumerable)

---

It looks like `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `IList` and their generic equivalents are in separate branches.

Comment: It's a pain in VB.Net, because you have to implement both interfaces with different names.

Comment: Also by branches I meant, they are like List vs List<T>, are independent of each other.

Answer (score 4):

It does this so that all older methods and code that knows how to handle an IEnumerable is guaranteed to work with your collections.

Implementing `IEnumerable<T>` implicitly means you implement `IEnumerable`.

By branches, do you mean namespaces?

Comment: Thanks. By branches I meant, they are like List vs List<T>, are independent of each other.

Comment: But couldn't they update those old methods to also work with the generic version?

Comment: This way old assemblies expecting IEnumerable will work with the IEnumerable<T> class. Sometimes there isn't source code to modify (ie., the new class is part of something that plugs into an existing app at runtime, someone using a library that provides only assemblies, no source).

Comment: Nor might it be worth the time to fix already working code like that.