# Why does ICollection<T> implement both IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, collections, ienumerable

Why does `ICollection<T>` implement both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`?

What is the purpose of this? How does `IEnumerable` benefit `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: Somewhat similar: [why-does-ienumerablet-inherit-from-ienumerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221691/why-does-ienumerablet-inherit-from-ienumerable?rq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The non-generic interface is for backward compatibility. If you write code using generics and want to pass your collection to some module written in .NET 1.0 (which doesn't have generics) you still want this to succeed, and you want the old method to be able to iterate through it.

Answer (score 13):

`IEnumerable<T>` itself forces any implementation to also implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`. This is safe, for the same reasons that `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant as of .NET 4... you can always convert the `T` to `object` for the non-generic form.

Basically this means that if you've got code which uses a parameter of type `IEnumerable`, you can still call it with something like `List<T>`.

Eric Lippert wrote a [blog post recently](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx) about why collections end up implementing many interfaces, and Brad Abrams wrote a [blog post back in 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx) about the specific `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerable` decision.

Answer (score -1):

`IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable` so it makes sense for `ICollection<T>` to as well.  It's just stating explicitly the inheritance that would be there anyway.