# Why IEnumerable<T> is defined as IEnumerable<out T>, not IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was IEnumerable<T> made covariant in C# 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732299/why-was-ienumerablet-made-covariant-in-c-sharp-4)

I was taking a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) for `IEnumerable<T>` interface definition, and see:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

I was wondering why T is defined as `out`, why not?

```
public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: because the interface is covariant

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732299/why-was-ienumerablet-made-covariant-in-c-sharp-4

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

The `out` makes the type parameter covariant. That is, you can use either the type or any derived types. Note that `out` only works this way with generics, it has a different meaning when used in method signatures (though you probably already knew that).

Here is the example taken from the [referenced page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

```
// Covariant interface. 
interface ICovariant<out R> { }

// Extending covariant interface. 
interface IExtCovariant<out R> : ICovariant<R> { }

// Implementing covariant interface. 
class Sample<R> : ICovariant<R> { }

class Program
{
    static void Test()
    {
        ICovariant<Object> iobj = new Sample<Object>();
        ICovariant<String> istr = new Sample<String>();

        // You can assign istr to iobj because 
        // the ICovariant interface is covariant.
        iobj = istr;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `out` in the interface signature allows 
you to assign an `ICovariant<String>` to an `ICovariant<Object>` variable, as `String` derives from `Object`. Without the `out` keyword, you would be unable to do this, as the types would be different.

You can read more about covariance (and the related contravariance) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

As other answers have pointed out, `IEnumerable` was only made covariant in .NET 4. Trying to write code such as:

```
IEnumerable<Object> strings = new List<string>();
```

will compile in .NET 4 and later versions, but not in previous versions.

Answer (score 7):

The `out` type parameter specifier denotes covariance.

In practice,

If I define two interfaces.

```
interface ISomeInterface<T>
{
}

interface ISomeCovariantInterface<out T> 
{
}
```

Then, I implement them like this.

```
class SomeClass<T> : ISomeInterface<T>, ISomeCovariantInterface<T>
{
}
```

Then I try to compile this code,

```
ISomeCovariantInterface<object> covariant = new SomeClass<string>(); // works
ISomeInterface<object> invariant = new SomeClass<string>(); // fails

// Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeClass<string>' to 'ISomeInterface<object>'.
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The is because the covariant interface allows more derived instances, where as, the standard interface does not.

[Fiddle Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CkP81L)

Comment: +1 I think this is the clearest, introduction level answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Covariance.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) This allows a collection to be assigned items of a more specific or derived type than what's specified in its generic param.

`IEnumerable<T>` wasn't always covariant; this was new to .NET 4, and the reason for the change is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732299/why-was-ienumerablet-made-covariant-in-c-sharp-4).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}

List<Derived> list = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> sequence = list;
```