# Is it possible to explicitly implement base interfaces more than once?

Tags: c#

If we have two interfaces with a common base that a class must implement, is it possible to explicitly implement the common base?

Consider `IEnumerable<T>` for example:

```
public class MyMultiEnumerable: IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<double>
{
    private readonly List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    private readonly List<double> doubleList = new List<double>();

    IEnumerator<double> IEnumerable<double>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return doubleList.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return intList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        /*
         * How do we deal with this common case, where in context it means
         * two different things?
         */
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have no requirement to do so, but I am interested from a theoretical perspective.

## Update #1

I think my use of `IEnumerable` and basic types is conflating this, and after thinking about it some more, I believe it could be stripped back to this problem:

```
public interface CommonBase
{
    void CommonMethod();
}

public interface AltBase1 : CommonBase
{
    void UnommonMethod();
}

public interface AltBase2 : CommonBase
{
    void UnommonMethod();
}

public class Example : AltBase1, AltBase2
{
    public void CommonMethod()
    {
        /*
         * If this method needs to know whether it is being called on behalf
         * of AltBase1 or AltBase2, how could it determine the implementation?
         */
    }

    void AltBase2.UnommonMethod()
    {

    }

    void AltBase1.UnommonMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Because it doesn't appear possible to explicitly implement an interface's inherited members (Example of how this might look below). I strongly believe this isn't possible via any conventional means, as it appears to be a multiple inheritance problem.

```
void AltBase1.CommonBase.CommonMethod()
{
    // AltBase1 targeted Implementation
}
```

Could it be achieved via any Meta-based approach, or not at all?

Comment: The problem is that it's confusing for the end-user, why not leverage a paradigm like `IConvertible` instead ?

Comment: I have had the realisation that my problem is probably completely invalid. In my use case the class would either be treated explicitly as an `IEnumerable<int>` or `IEnumerable<double>`, and never as an `IEnumerable`. Since the method names are the same `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()` should never be called, and an `InvalidOperationException` or similar should be thrown. I need to mull over this some more.

Comment: Your code might not but say, if you use LINQ, it will at some point. By the way, `IEnumerator GetEnumerator` is generally implemented as simply returning the result of the specialized overload. TL;DR you must implement both overloads.

Comment: Sure it's possible.   And back before `IEnumerable<T>` was made covariant in [c# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6732299) you would sometimes see classes that implement, say, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<object>`  Usually the generic with the most derived parameter would be directly implemented and the generic with the base parameter would be explicit.  `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<double>` would be very strange though -- and would confuse almost all serializers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I think it's a code smell. The only scenario where this is viable is as you've phrased it - when implementing a specific version for a generic class. In that scenario, you should be leveraging the type variables, rather than how you've got it right now.

Answer (score 0):

So you can get it to a point where you can compile your code. From the IEnumerable interface you have to implement `GetEnumerator()`, but you have to decide if you want to return `intList` or `doubleList`. Both `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<double>` have the same signature on `GetEnumerator()` so there's no way to implement them both since the compiler will complain.

Take a look at this post as it has good compatible/incompatible examples of how to deal with interfaces with the same method.

[Implementing two interfaces in a class with same method. Which interface method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method)