# One razor component rendering base class properties of different classes

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm new in Blazor programming and it might be that my question was already answered, but I didn't found an answer solving my problem.

I have a Base class:

```cs
    public class DomainModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

which is imported in several other classes like:

```cs
    public class Class1 : DomainModel
    {
       public string AnotherText1 {get;set;}
    }
    public class Class2 : DomainModel
    {
       public string AnotherText2 {get;set;}
    }
```

My pages to be rendered.

```cs
PageClass1.razor
List<Class1> list1
<ListComponent />

PageClass2.razor
List<Class2> list2
<ListComponent />
```

The razor `ListComponent` should render the `DomainModel` properties of `list1` or `list2`.
How can I do that?

Comment: What is `ListComponent`?

Comment: You can access the base class properties from derived class. However, if you want to show properties of derived class based on the actual instance passed (Class1 or Class2) you need to cast them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6732299/60761) parameter.
An `IEnumerable<DomainModel>` will accept both lists.

ListComponent.razor

```
@foreach(DomainModel item in Items)
{
   ...
}

@code
{
   [Parameter, EditorRequired]
   public IEnumerable<DomainModel> Items  {get; set; }  // not a List<>
}
```

and then the usage looks like

```
PageClass1.razor
List<Class1> list1
<ListComponent Items="list1" />

PageClass2.razor
List<Class2> list2
<ListComponent Items="list2" />
```

Comment: Many thanks. It helped. Nevertheless looking at the browser console it shows the error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
It is pointig the ListComponent in line 3:

Comment: That is an unrelated problem, you will of course have to initialize the 2 lists.