# Override IEnumerable<T> in More Derived Class - Any Potential Issues?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a abstract, custom collection type we'lll call `AnimalCollection` for storing a collection of `Animal` objects. Animals that need to be stored in an animal collection are so special that they get their own implementation of `AnimalCollection` for storing additional information specific to that type of collection, e.g. `TurtleCollection`, `GiraffeCollection`, etc.

Since we're all collections here, I think it makes sense that `AnimalCollection` should implement `IEnumerable<Animal>` so users can iterate over it. However, in the case of our more derived classes it makes more sense to have implemented `IEnumerable<Turtle>`, `IEnumerable<Giraffe>`, etc.

```cs
class Animal {}
class Turtle : Animal {}

abstract class AnimalCollection : IEnumerable<Animal>
{
}

class TurtleCollection : AnimalCollection, IEnumerable<Turtle>
{
}
```

That way, when someone does `foreach (var turtle in turtleCollection)` `var` is automatically of type `Turtle`. Without having implemented `IEnumerable<Turtle>`, the user would have had to type `foreach (Turtle turtle in turtleCollection)`. Since I always type `var` everywhere I can, I'm sure I would eventually trip over the fact my `turtle` variable wasn't casted to the type I expected, which means the users of my API would probably stumble over this as well!

So [while I'm aware that having a type implement `IEnumerable<T>` on two *adjacent* types in an inheritance tree can cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851014/a-class-with-multiple-ienumerablet-interfaces-on-it-what-to-do-with-the-non), I'm wondering whether there could be hidden gotchas in using multiple `IEnumerable<T>` with types in the same inheritance hierarchy?

---

EDIT: The most sensible solution here would be to have `AnimalCollection<T>` and then define `TurtleCollection : AnimalCollection<Turtle>` as has been pointed out by some of the existing comments/answers. However the reason my `AnimalCollection` is non-generic is that the type I'm calling `AnimalCollection` actually represents a *node* in a *tree*. In actuality, I have types like

```cs
class Node {}
class FooNode : Node {}
class BarNode : Node {}

class NodeCollection : Node {}
class FooNodeCollection : NodeCollection {}
class BarNodeCollection : NodeCollection {}
```

`FooNodeCollection` is constrained in its constructor to only take objects of type `FooNode`. I then have visitors for accessing the nodes of a tree

```cs
class NodeVisitor
{
    abstract void VisitFoo(FooNode foo);
    abstract void VisitBar(BarNode bar);
    abstract void VisitCollection(NodeCollection collection);
}
```

The exact type of node that is contained in the `NodeCollection` doesn't really matter as far as visitors are concerned; all the visitor will do is simply iterate over its children and have them dispatch themselves to the visitor.

Potentially one solution then could be to have two types - `NodeCollection` which is used by the visitor, and `NodeCollection<T>` which derives from `NodeCollection` and is the one that actually implements `IEnumerable<T>`, however I'm also interested to know what types of issues could arise from utilizing multiple `IEnumerable<T>` in the way originally stated

Comment: Why your `AnimalCollection` is not generic? Why don't you just create a `class AnimalCollection<TAnimal> : IEnumerable<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal`?

Comment: I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784982/10102452) based on your additional information.

Comment: Experience has taught me that it's almost always better to use plain old generic collections rather than creating custom collection classes. What value does `AnimalCollection`, `TurtleCollection`, etc., provide more than you could get from `IReadOnlyCollection<Animal>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<Turtle>`, etc.?

Comment: Put your Information "you can only put a Foobar in 'this' collection' somewhere else.
Add a Type-Property, and put Validation Code in your add-method, or put your validation outside the collection anyway. In this tree-scenario you will not get around casting. In most scenarios you get runtime errors, in case of  'doing something wrong'. What you try to do is, getting compile time errors, when coding something wrong. At some point in time you will necessarily have a collection of different types. Like as List<Node>. Compiler loses control what object has what type and cannot show you the error

Answer (score 1):

I'd structure the code to use [composition, not inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

```
class Animal {}
class Turtle : Animal { public Color ShellColor {get;set;} }

abstract class AnimalCollection<T> where T : Animal
{
   public IEnumerable<T> Animals {get; set;} 
}

class TurtleCollection : AnimalCollection<Turtle> {}

(...)
foreach( var t in new TurtleCollection().Animals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.ShellColor);
}
```

---

*(Update)*

Oh, yeah, [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt) is always a good read as well.

Answer (score 0):

An additional [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852650/10102452) to the question you linked to also hints at why multiple implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` for types in the same inheritance hierarchy would be bad. If you consider the scenario of the answer, trying to cast to the base type would leave the runtime making an *undefined* choice, which is something that you should, to quote the answer: **Avoid, avoid, avoid**.

Beyond that, let me remind you of `OfType<T>`:

```
foreach (var turtle in collection.OfType<Turtle>())
{
    //turtle is guaranteed to be of type Turtle.
    //If no Turtle objects exist in the collection,
    //the iteration will simply not execute!
}
```

And, finally, your posted code would definitely be clearer if you followed the suggestion of [Federico Dipuma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784855/override-ienumerablet-in-more-derived-class-any-potential-issues#comment103853005_58784855):

Just create a class `AnimalCollection<TAnimal> : IEnumerable<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal`.

## EDIT

Based on the updated question, my understanding is that the visitor does something along these lines:

```
public void VisitCollection(NodeCollection node)
{
    //The problem is that, here, there is no way to know
    //(without pattern-matching or type checks in general)
    //what node type the collection contains. However
    //it may not matter at all, so there should be no problem.
}
```

Your problem would arise wherever you would be coding with access to both `IEnumerable<T>` implementations, i.e. wherever you have access to the specific class type rather than the base type. The `VisitCollection` method is certainly not one of these cases, because within the scope of the method, you only know (cf. see) an `IEnumerable<Node>` and not an `IEnumerable<FooNode>` or otherwise. Therefore, you are not "in danger" inside this method.

If, however, your visitor needs to know the specific node type in case of collections, you would have:

```
public abstract class Visitor
{
    //As in your case...
    abstract void VisitFooNodeCollection(FooNodeCollection collection);
    abstract void VisitBarNodeCollection(BarNodeCollection collection);
}
```

In these cases, you **might** have trouble using `var` (I say "might" because it is more like "undefined behavior") because `FooNodeCollection` is both `IEnumerable<Node>` and `IEnumerable<FooNode>` (if I understand correctly). So, in that context, whenever you type `var`, you might have the problem you mention, i.e. the runtime will not know what to cast your object to.

However, the use of inherited (rather than adjacent) hierarchy types gives you the option to resolve the inconsistency using `OfType<T>`. If the runtime gets the enumerator of the base type, your objects are certainly of the base type, so they will all be enumerated. If the enumerator of the derived type runs, of course your objects have been constrained (by the constructor), so your are still safe and they will definitely be of that specific type, hence all will be enumerated.

In short, if you are casting to the correct type with `OfType<T>`, you should not have a problem, plus the `var` will be of the cast type T, so you will have compile-time analysis. However, because I think you are probably OK with the visitor and you only take into account what to do with a type only at the single-node level, you will probably not run into this type of problem, as you will be operating within the "collection-type-agnostic" `VisitCollection` scope. In that case, though, I don't see why you would want to make the inheriting classes implement `IEnumerable<DerivedType>` as well.

Comment: If the `TurtleCollection` were constrained in its constructor to only take objects of type `Turtle`, we wouldn't have a problem doing things like `OfType<T>`. I tested using `OfType<T>` on a type with inherited `IEnumerable<T>` in the way my question asks; the `IEnumerable<T>` on `TurtleCollection` is always called by `OfType`, regardless of whether `collection` has been casted to `AnimalCollection` or `TurtleCollection`. I guess that's not what I expected, but I'm not sure it's necessarily a problem; in the end we were able to iterate and wound up with an object casted correctly

Comment: Yes, `foreach` first runs `GetEnumerator`, so the "base" enumerable is whatever your class implements it to be. Thereafter, `.OfType<T>()` (note the dot) just performs the casting and ignores "non-castable" objects (in contrast to `Cast<T>()` which throws), thus returning a **different** enumerable.