# Getting most specific interface for two types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to get the most specific interface that both types implement. Getting the list of interfaces is fairly easy:

```
var interfaces = leftType.GetInterfaces().Intersect(rightType.GetInterfaces());
```

Then, I traverse the list and remove interfaces that are "included" into other interfaces:

```
var remaining = interfaces.ToDictionary(i => i, i => true);
foreach(var iface in interfaces)
    foreach(var subIface in iface.GetInterfaces())
        remaining.Remove(subIface);
```

However, when trying to get the most common interface for `int[]` and `List<int>`, I get a list of three interfaces:

- `IList` (non-generic)
- `IList<int>`
- `IReadOnlyList<int>`

First of all, why doesn't `IList<T>` implement non-generic `IList`, while `IEnumerable<T>` does actually implement `IEnumerable`?

Then, the `IReadOnlyList` causes a certain confusion. The name implies that the container that implements the interface *prohibits* modification, but the usage, on the contrary, implies that the container allows read access and doesn't care about modifications. But if so, why doesn't `IList<T>` implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`?

Maybe the whole approach is incorrect, and there's a more clever way to detect the most specific interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559070/why-generic-ilist-does-not-inherit-non-generic-ilist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221691/why-does-ienumerablet-inherit-from-ienumerable

Answer (score 3):

`IList<T>` doesn't implement `IList` because `IList<T>` allows you to pass objects in. Allowing the usage of a non-generic interface here would break type safety.
Imagine this:

```
IList list = new List<WhateverClass>();
list.Add(new object()); // Runtime error because the type doesn't match
```

`IEnumerable<T>` only allows you to get objects out though, not pass them in (`T` is covariant). You can iterate over the elements of an `IEnumerable<T>` and treat all items like `object`s. So `IEnumerable<T>` can implement `IEnumerable` without problems.

Also, the fact that `List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>` just implies that `List<T>` fulfills the contract required by the interface (which doesn't explicitly prohibit being actually modifiable).
If you just need read access to a list, you can treat a `List<T>` like a readonly list.

Comment: But if `List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`, why doesn't `IList<T>` do the same?

Comment: @Impworks Not sure about the exact reasons, but if you look closely, `IReadOnlyList<out T>` has a covariant type parameter, while `IList<T>` just has a normal type parameter. I'm not sure how that is compatible (haven't tried it).

Comment: this kinda clarifies it. `IReadOnlyList<T>` looks like an extended version of `IEnumerable<T>` which knows its length.

Comment: @Impworks: For whatever reason, Microsoft decided that a read-only property, a write property, and a read-write property should be three independent things, rather than having a "read-write property" simply be the combination of a read-only property and a read-write property.  Because `IReadOnlyList<T>` includes a *read-only* indexer, `IList<T>` does not, a version of `IList<T>` which inherited `IReadOnlyList<T>` would be incompatible with existing `IList<T>` implementations.  If Microsoft were to implement a feature I've long wished for--the ability for an interface...

Comment: ...to include a static generic class with default implementations of the interface members (i.e. static functions whose first parameter is of the generic type) then `IList<T>` could inherit from `IReadOnlyList<T>` by including a default implementation of the read-only property which would chain to the read-write one.

Comment: @Botz3000: It's clear why `IList<T>` can't implement `IReadOnlyList<T>` absent some major (but IMHO desirable) changes to the Framework.  Can you think of any reason `IList<T>` should not have implemented the non-generic `ICollection` [thus providing a means for code which expects an `IEnumerable<Animal>` to ascertain (without enumeration) the number of items in any object which implements `IList<Cat>`]